# Sharepoint view in outlook

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, outlook

Is it possible to see SharePoint 2013 filtered VIEW in outlook. Currently i am able to see all events of SharePoint Calendar in outlook which i don't want.

I have created one view, which i want show in outlook. Is it possible OOTB?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook imports the default calendar *data* as that is what it supports. Any filtered views only will work in SharePoint. sorry.